# Running interceptor in Struts

Tags: java, struts2, web

I have been trying to run the following code in my project .The whole project works fine but the interceptor part does not show any result.I am new to the interceptor part so please advise me if my code lacks something.I also wish to know if the only change to be done to run interceptor is to be done in struts.xml file by adding the interceptor tags??

```
enter code here  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
   <interceptors>  
   <interceptor name="timer" class=".."/>
   <interceptor name="logger" class=".."/>
   </interceptors>
   <action name="HelloWorld">
      <result>/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      <interceptor-ref name="timer"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>
    </action>
    <action name="SayHello" class="com.sapient.test.HelloAction">

        <result name="SUCCESS">/HelloWorld/DisplayHello.jsp</result>
        <result name="INPUT">/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
           <interceptor-ref name="timer"/>
           <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>

    </action>
</package>
```

Please note that the rest part of the web app was working fine when I added the interceptor piece of code. Rest of the web app runs as it ran but the interceptor part is not working. Its not a caching problem coz I tried cleaning the server and the directories multiple times but to no effect.Please please help.

Comment: you need to configure the other interceptors also (under default stack) like or use `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>` after you defined your own stack.have a look here http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/interceptor-configuration.html

Comment: I tried but am still confused could u pls guide me where exactly shall i add the piece of code

Comment: u picked up the code from the docs but that is for descriton only, can you also specify what exactly you mean by *interceptor part is not working. Its not a caching problem* and what you trying to do ?

Comment: I mean i have this basic code of entering a text box field and displaying the entered value which is running as expected..but I can't see any output corresponding to the interceptors i have added i.e say the time taken to run corresponding to the timer interceptor etc.Do I need to make some changes in the action file or any other files??

Comment: you are using the build in interceptors, are you using proper logging to see output?

Comment: What logging shall I use to see the appropriate output?please clarify and also please note that I am not using any maven etc build to run the app just using eclipse run on server option,in this respect what modifications shall I make?

Comment: you must be using log4j, use logging as info or debug,

Comment: Take a peek in the struts-core-x.x.x jar, in the default package there is a file called struts-default.xml this is where all the struts2 interceptors,interceptor stacks, results types... it is quite educational, you will build your stacks in the same way so it is worth remembering there is always a good example at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Please configure interceptor in struts.xml like below,

```
 <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="......." />
        <interceptor-stack name="loginInterceptorStack">
          <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor" />
          <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptors>
```

Then apply your interceptor stack to actions,

```
  <action name="..." class=".....">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptorStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="input">.....</result>
        <result name="success">...../result>
    </action>
```

Add interceptor before result in action configuration. Also add proper logging in your interceptor so you can know before calling default stack your interceptor is called.